# From vec-trick to matrix-trick for Kronecker products

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra, kronecker-product, vectorization

for the vec-trick of the Kronecker product, we can write

$$
\left(\mathbf{B}^{\top} \otimes \mathbf{A}\right) \operatorname{vec}(\mathbf{X})=\operatorname{vec}(\mathbf{A} \mathbf{X} \mathbf{B}).
$$

I am wondering whether this could be extended to the case of higher-order tensors. Now we are going from a vector to a matrix. Can I reshape the following formula

$$
\left(\mathbf{B}^{\top} \otimes \mathbf{A}\right) \mathbf{X}
$$

in something similar to the one above, but where now I have a matrix on the right multiplication? I would like going from a 2D matrix to a 3D matrix in a way. 
Did you ever encounter this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $X$ consists of the columns $\{c_k\},\,$ i.e.
$\,X = \big[\matrix{c_1&c_2&\ldots&c_n}\big]$

Consider that each column can be associated with a corresponding matrix $\,c_k={\rm vec}(C_k)$

Reversing the "vec-trick" yields
$\;(B^T\otimes A) c_k = {\rm vec}(AC_kB)$

Therefore
$$\eqalign{
(B^T\otimes A) X
 &= (B^T\otimes A)\big[\matrix{c_1&c_2&\ldots&c_n}\big] \\
 &= \Big[\matrix{
 {\rm vec}(AC_1B)
&{\rm vec}(AC_2B)
&\ldots
&{\rm vec}(AC_nB)}\Big] \\
}$$
which is a partition-wise vectorization of the matrix.

By introducing the standard basis vectors $\{e_k\}$
this can be written more compactly
$$\eqalign{
(B^T\otimes A) X
 &= (B^T\otimes A)\;\sum_{k=1}^nc_ke_k^T \\
 &= \big(B^T\otimes A\big)\,c_ke_k^T
 \qquad&\big({\rm Einstein\,Convention}\big) \\
 &= {\rm vec}\big(AC_kB\big)\,e_k^T \\
}$$
One could consider $C_k$ matrix to be the $k^{th}$ component
of a third-order tensor $\Gamma$
$$C_k = \Gamma e_k\quad\implies\quad\Gamma = C_ke_k^T$$
The third-order tensor $\Omega$ can be used to define the vec-operation
$$\eqalign{
\Omega_{ijk} &= \begin{cases}
1\quad{\rm if}\;i=j+rk-r \\
0\quad{\rm otherwise}
\end{cases} \\
\Omega_{ijk}M_{jk} &= {\rm vec}(M)_i \\
\Omega:M &= {\rm vec}(M) \\
M &\in {\mathbb R}^{r\times c},\quad\;
\Omega\in{\mathbb R}^{rc\times r\times c} \\
X &= c_ke_k^T = (\Omega:C_k)e_k^T = \Omega:\Gamma \\
}$$
allowing the solution to be compacted even further
$$\eqalign{
(B^T\otimes A) X
 &= {\rm vec}\big(AC_kB\big)\,e_k^T \\
 &= \big(\Omega:AC_kB\big)e_k^T \\
 &= \big(\Omega B^T:AC_k\big)e_k^T \\
 &= \Omega B^T:A\Gamma \\
}$$
Of course, I don't recommend doing *any* of this, since these operations are not well-known, or as simple the original Kronecker product.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. And how is a way to write it in a more compact form that highlight the tensor form? More in general, if I have a higher order tensor, I think I should arrive on a sort of recursion equation where I have also more matrix $A$ and $B$. Do you have some idea?